# Removing the keydown handler and adding it to a new textbox, which is created inside the handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started trying to use jQuery in my app and since I'm not very familiar with it, I was quickly stopped by a seemingly simple issue.

My view has one textbox, with the id "line0". This will be assigned the keydown handler. When I press TAB inside the textbox, this should happen:

- add a new, identical textbox with incremented id (e.g. line1, line2)
- remove the keydown handler from the first textbox
- add the keydown handler to the new textbox

This is so that the handler is only fired when TAB is pressed in the last textbox, and when TAB is pressed in any of the earlier textboxes, it will just perform default behavior.

Adding the textbox works, the handles is removed and focus shifts to my new textbox. But when I press TAB in my new textbox, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I assume this is because I removed an anonymous function and then tried to add it to a different element. How can I move this to a named function so I can use it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lines = $("#lines");
    var count = 0;

    $("#line0").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var keydown = $("#line" + count).keydown;

            $("#line" + count).off("keydown");

            count++;

            $(lines).append('<input id="line' + count + '" type="text" />');
            $("#line" + count).focus();
            $("#line" + count).on("keydown", keydown)
        }
    })
});
```

**Edit:**
I forgot to use #, so obviously jquery couldn't find the elements I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution, I simply have to save the anonymous function to a variable when I'm creating it. I can then call it by that name later in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lines = $("#lines");
    var count = 0;

    $("#line0").on("keydown", $handler = function (e) {
        if (e.which == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("#line" + count).off("keydown");

            count++;

            $(lines).append('<input id="line' + count + '" type="text" />');
            $("#line" + count).focus();
            $("#line" + count).on("keydown", $handler)
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go, also you missed some `#` indicator of the id for your dynamically added inputs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lines = $("#lines");
    var count = 0;
    function keyDownFunc (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#rule" + count).off("keydown");

                count++;

                $(lines).append('<input id="rule' + count + '" type="text" />');
                $("#rule" + count).focus();
                $(document).on('keydown','#rule'+count,keyDownFunc(e));
            }
        };
    $(document).on("keydown","#rule0", keyDownFunc(e));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. It throws an error that says e is not defined.